# From a security standpoint, should bloginfo() or get_bloginfo() be escaped?

Tags: security, options, escaping, bloginfo

I've been reviewing a lot of information about WP theme and plugin security and understand the concept that you should escape attributes and HTML values in themes and plugins. I've seen `bloginfo()` and `echo get_bloginfo()` used both standard and inside an `esc_html()` or `esc_attr()` function.

***Genesis*** and ***_s***, Automattic's base theme both escape these values but WP's own codex theme standards guide does not say anything about escaping these values. I've looked into the WP code (`wp-includes/option.php`) and it seems like that there's a little sanitization of values passed from `get_option()` but it also looks like there's a filter that a plugin could overwrite for certain values.

It's this fact that leads me toward thinking that it should be escaped. Can anyone enlighten me on this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

We have to look a bit deeper here to get an answer to your question.

So, `bloginfo` is a simple wrapper around `get_bloginfo`.

```
<?php
function bloginfo( $show='' ) {
    echo get_bloginfo( $show, 'display' );
}
```

Notice the second argument `display`. Let's see what that does.

```
<?php
function get_bloginfo( $show = '', $filter = 'raw' ) {

    // snip snip, $output is fetched somewhere in here

    if ( 'display' == $filter ) {
        if ( $url )
            $output = apply_filters('bloginfo_url', $output, $show);
        else
            $output = apply_filters('bloginfo', $output, $show);
    }

    return $output;
}
```

If the filter is set to `display` the output of `get_bloginfo` is run through a filter.

Rather than hardcode something like a call to `esc_html` in a function, WP uses it's own hook system to do things.  The place to find that where that happens is in `wp-includes/default-filters.php`.  A quick search for `bloginfo` in that file reveals...

```
<?php
// Format strings for display.
foreach ( array( 'comment_author', 'term_name', 'link_name', 'link_description', 'link_notes', 'bloginfo', 'wp_title', 'widget_title' ) as $filter ) {
    add_filter( $filter, 'wptexturize'   );
    add_filter( $filter, 'convert_chars' );
    add_filter( $filter, 'esc_html'      );
}
```

`bloginfo` is hidden in the `foreach` array. As you can see, the output of `bloginfo` gets escaped with `esc_html`.

In other words, this:

```
<?php
bloginfo('name');
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
<?php
echo esc_html(get_bloginfo('name'));
```

Or this:

```
<?php
echo get_bloginfo('name', 'display');
```

So, no, the output of `bloginfo` does not need to be escaped.  Neither does the output of `get_bloginfo` as long as the second argument is set to `display`.

The caveat, however, is that anyone can remove the `esc_html` filter from `bloginfo`.  So it's likely safer just to escape the output. And, of course, if you're using the output of `bloginfo` for anything other than HTML display (eg. in the alt attribute of an image), you should run it through `esc_attr`.

Comment: Might be worth checking the version the use of filter was introduced. It might be that _s and genesis where published in an older version that didn't include this code.

Comment: `esc_html` has been around since 2.8, so has it being hooked into `bloginfo` https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/2.8-branch/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L78-L84

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks. I'm only just now getting into the guts of WP and although it was clear to me that bloginfo was a get_bloginfo wrapper, it was not clear that the output was being sanitized. I missed the filters. I should perhaps become more familiar with how WP handles code that enters and leaves the database. I'm left with a similar outlook as when I started but at least I know why now :)